# Q.fcall always goes into fail

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var Q = require('q')
var fs = require('fs')
var deferred = Q.defer()

function GetDTImage (PicName) {
  fs.readFile(process.cwd() + '\\' + PicName + '.jpg', function (error, text) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error)
    } else {
      return text.toString('base64')
    }
  })
}

Q.fcall(GetDTImage('Dogs'))
  .then(
      function (imgBase64Code) {
        console.log(imgBase64Code)
    }, function (err) {console.log(err)}
)
```

Hello everyone, here is a question bothering me for a time.

I am confused why the above code always performs the error message,  **Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined**,

Comment: `GetDTImage` returns undefined ... always, you have no return statement, therefore undefined is returned... what does Q.fcall expect as an argument? a function ... hence it's trying to call the passed in argument using the Function#apply method ... undefined has no methods, not even apply... even if you fix this error, `GetDTImage` doesn't return a promise, so you still wont get what you need

Comment: I have already replace `return text.toString('base64')` to `deferred.resolve(text.toString('base64'))
     return deferred.promise`, but still show the same error

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Q.fcall expects a function as the first argument, and optional arguments for that function as subsequent arguments

so, you need to use Q.fcall like this

```
Q.fcall(GetDTImage, 'Dogs')
  .then(
      function (imgBase64Code) {
        console.log(imgBase64Code)
    }, function (err) {console.log(err)}
)
```

However, this would resolve to the value (or promise) returned by calling

```
GetDTImage('Dogs')
```

But your function GetDTImage doesn't return anything - the only return statement is inside the callback inside that function!

effectively your GetDTImage funciton is

```
function GetDTImage (PicName) {
    // go and do this asynchronous thing
    fs.readFile(process.cwd() + '\\' + PicName + '.jpg', function (error, text) {
        if (error) {
            return reject(error);
        }
        resolve(text.toString('base64'));
    });
    // but return straight away regardless of that asynchronous thing
    return undefined;
}
```

because fs.readFile is asynchronous, you need GetDTImage to return a promise for it to work

```
function GetDTImage (PicName) {
    // here we return a promise, huzzah!
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile(process.cwd() + '\\' + PicName + '.jpg', function (error, text) {
            if (error) {
                return reject(error);
            }
            resolve(text.toString('base64'));
        });
    });
}
```

Now you can either

```
Q.fcall(GetDTImage, 'Dogs')
  .then(
      function (imgBase64Code) {
        console.log(imgBase64Code)
    }, function (err) {console.log(err)}
)
```

or

```
Q.fcall(GetDTImage('Dogs'))
  .then(
      function (imgBase64Code) {
        console.log(imgBase64Code)
    }, function (err) {console.log(err)}
)
```

(I'm sure there's a difference between those two, but I'm not familiar enough with `Q` to accurately define that difference

However, since GetDTImage now returns a promise, you may as well do this:

```
GetDTImage('Dogs')
  .then(
      function (imgBase64Code) {
        console.log(imgBase64Code)
    }, function (err) {console.log(err)}
)
```

and forget Q.fcall altogether

Answer (score 0):

```
var Q = require('q')
var fs = require('fs')
var deferred = Q.defer()

function GetDTImage (PicName) {
  fs.readFile(process.cwd() + '\\' + PicName + '.jpg', function (error, text) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error)
    } else {
     deferred.resolve(text.toString('base64'))
    }
  })
  return deferred.promise
}

GetDTImage(Dogs)
  .then(
      function (imgBase64Code) {
        console.log(imgBase64Code)
    }, function (err) {console.log(err)}
)
```

Thanks Jaromanda's support.
I have solved it and here is my solution.